# Pointer array of strings size and address spacing do not match

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, size

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I am trying to teach myself some programming and fell into a little confusion here. The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int i;

    char *array[5]={"Apples", "mangoes", "grapes", "bananas", "oranges"};

    printf("THIS IS FROM THE ARRAY:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("String=%s | ", array[i]);
        printf("Address of string literal = %i", array[i]);
        printf(" | Size = %u\n",sizeof(array[i]));
    }
}
```

produces the output:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNAnd.png)

```
THIS IS FROM THE ARRAY:
String=Apples | Address of string literal = 4210688 | Size = 8
String=mangoes | Address of string literal = 4210695 | Size = 8
String=grapes | Address of string literal = 4210703 | Size = 8
String=bananas | Address of string literal = 4210710 | Size = 8
String=oranges | Address of string literal = 4210718 | Size = 8
```

Why is the differences between the addresses not consistently 8 although the sizeof output says the size is eight?

*4210688 4210695 (Difference is 7)
4210695 4210703 (Difference is 8)
4210703 4210710 (Difference is 7)
4210710 4210718 (Difference is 8)*

And if my suspicion is correct (that these are not the addresses of where the strings are in memory but just address of the pointers or something), how would I change my code to list the addresses of where the actual strings reside in memory?
I am on a Windows 64 bit system using Code Blocks IDE, GNU GCC Compiler. If you need any more relevant info I will be happy to provide them.

Comment: "Why is the differences between the addresses not consistently 8" (?) --> Try printing the address of the array elements with `printf("Address of string literal = %p", &array[i]);` rather than the value of the array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when printing addresses you should use the `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `void *`.

That being said, the addresses being printed *are* the addresses of where the strings are stored.  If you look closely at the differences between the address of each pointer, you'll see that these differences exactly match the size of each string.  String literals are typically stored in a read-only data segment, and in this case each of your strings happen to be consecutive in memory.

If you were to print the address of each array element (each of which is a pointer) then you would see a difference of 8 between each of them.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(array[i])` gives you the size of a `char *` not the length of the string. Use `strlen()+1` for the number of bytes in a string.

The difference of 7 makes perfect sense for a 6-letter word (+ terminating NUL character).

Also, as chux says you should use `%p` to print a pointer value (and to be extra correct, the argument should be cast to `(void *)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can find out that the array of `char*` exists consecutively if you print `strlen(array[i])` instead of `sizeof(array[i])`.

`main()` should return int. `void main()` is not a standard.

You should declare `const char*` for your array, not `char*`. It is not modifiable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    const char* array[5] = { "Apples", "mangoes", "grapes", "bananas", "oranges" };

    printf("THIS IS FROM THE ARRAY:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("String=%s | ", array[i]);
        printf("Address of string literal = %i", array[i]);
        printf(" | Size = %u\n", strlen(array[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```